# Recursive javascript function

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is file1:

```
file1
include file2;
```

this is file2:

```
file2
include file3;
```

this is file3:

```
file3
include file4;
```

this is file4:

```
file4
```

The end result should be:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

Whats wrong with this?

```
function recurse(data, callback) {
    if (data.match(/include(.*)\;/)) {
        var fn = data.match(/include(.*)\;/)[1];
        var filetxt = readfile(fn);
        recurse(filetxt, callback);
    } else {
        callback(data);
    }
}
var txt = recurse(readfile('file1'), function(s) {
    console.log(s);
})
```

Comment: What does it do instead of what you expect?

Comment: Does `readfile` ignore leading whitespace? Right you're passing in filenames with a leading space because the match group in `/include(.*)\;/` captures the space between `include` and `fileN`.

Comment: @apsillers may have hit the nail on the head.  Try to change the regex to `/include (.*)\;/`

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you what is wrong if you don't tell us what it currently does?

Comment: Besides any other problems with the JS syntax, there's one of misparsing.  Try putting "This file doesn't include anything; it's just text" in file4, and watch what happens.  You should probably at least be anchoring the pattern to the start of a line.

Comment: @cHao I agree, but the OP isn't reading line by line. Which would cause us to think they **should** be for something like this :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to

```
/include (.*)\;/
```

so that the match group catches `"fileN"` instead of `" fileN"` (note the leading space).